# JSON как правильно распарсить

Tags: c#

Как правильно распарсить.

```
var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(@"{
    'streetAddress:word': 'Московское ш., 201, кв.200',
    'city': 'Москва',
    'postalCode': 201201
},{
    'streetAddress:word': 'Московское ш., 201, кв.220',
    'city': 'Тверь',
    'postalCode': 2222
}");
```

Comment: Ну так правильно выглядит, проблема в чём?

Comment: @Monk, в том, что несколько объектов пытается не объединенных в массив

Comment: добавь `[`,`]` вокруг json: `@"[{...},{...}]"` и разбирай как `Test[]`

Comment: Мне нужен 2 вариант получить после запятой

Comment: так и десериализуй только его

Comment: Давайте другой вариант покажу:  {"id":"2","time":"1480325098","count":"10181","name":"Тест1","product_id":"2"},{"id":"7","time":"1482757410","count":"10","name":"Тест2","product_id":"3"}

Comment: Как мне получить всю эту информацию без быдлятины.

Comment: Я же уже сказал как, смотри мой комментарий выше: разбираешь как массив, а потом берешь то что надо

Answer (score 3):

Воспользовавшись комментарием [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) и сайтом, который легко дает модель для json (http://jsonutils.com/)

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _608123
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var json = @"[{
    'streetAddress:word': 'Московское ш., 201, кв.200',
    'city': 'Москва',
    'postalCode': 201201
},{
    'streetAddress:word': 'Московское ш., 201, кв.220',
    'city': 'Тверь',
    'postalCode': 2222
}]";
      var examples = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example[]>(json);
      var lastExample = examples.Last();
    }
  }
  public class Example
  {

    [JsonProperty("streetAddress:word")]
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postalCode")]
    public int postalCode { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = "мой json";
List<Test> test= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(json,new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
Test p1 = test[0];
Test p2 = test[1];
Test p3 = test[2];
```

Comment: чем данный код отличается от кода в вопросе?